# How can you modify an in-use dll?

Tags: .net, windows, multithreading

If I have multiple instances of the same process accessing some dll, is there a way for one of these processes to obtain the lock on it, delete it, replace it, and continue?

Comment: It is possible to delete and replace a dll that is in use via [Assembly Shadow Copying](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279(v=vs.110).aspx), but running exe's will still be using the old version till they are stopped and restarted. Is that acceptable? If so I can write up a answer summarizing how to do it.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that'd work fantastically, actually.

Comment: You cannot delete a DLL that is loaded in a process.  The code in the DLL is mapped into memory with a memory mapped file.  The operating system prevents deletion to ensure that the process will not randomly crash with a paging fault.  At best you can rename the file.

Comment: @HansPassant What you say is true, but you can get somewhat of a workaround via Shadow Copied files. That makes the memory mapped file a copied version of the dll instead of the original, leaving the original unlocked so it can be modified (just don't expect any modifications to show up on the copied version, you need to restart the AppDomain to do that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to replace dll's that are in use the programs using them must have their app domain in "[Shadow Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279(v=vs.110).aspx)" mode. What this does is instead of using the file directly the assembly makes a copy of the file and loads that copy in to memory. This allows you to replace or delete a DLL of a currently running application, when the application is next restarted it will grab a new copy of the current version. This is how IIS makes it possible for you to update a website that is in use, it shadow copies its assemblies and when it detects a change to the directory it restarts the website loading the new versions of your assembiles.

The Shadow Copy setting is a [AppDomain level setting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.shadowcopyfiles(v=vs.110).aspx), however once a AppDomain is started you can not change the setting.

The two ways to enable Shadow Copy is either use a small "Loader" app domain that starts before your program, this loader starts a new AppDomain with Shadow Copy enabled then starts your assembly.

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ShadowCopyFiles == false)
    {

        var assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        var currentAppDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("ShadowedDomain", 
            null,
            currentAppDomain.BaseDirectory,
            currentAppDomain.RelativeSearchPath, 
            true); //<-- This true is what enables Shadow Copy on the AppDomain.

        //This calls Main again in the new AppDomain and blocks till the call to Main exits.
        newDomain.ExecuteAssembly(assembly.Location, args);
     }
    else
    {
        RealMain(args);
    }
}

private static void RealMain(string[] args)
{
    //Your code here.
}
```

One drawback is your main EXE will still be locked but any DLL's your EXE loads will be loaded using Shadow Copy.

---

The other option is similar to the first, but you can tell your own assembly to use a custom loader to enable Shadow Copy instead of manually running the loader and pointing it to your assembly. To do this first make a separate dll that will act as the loader and have it contain a class derived from `AppDomainManager`, this file will not be shadow copied.

```
using System;

namespace DomainManager
{
    public class ShadowDomainManager : AppDomainManager
    {
        public override void InitializeNewDomain(AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo)
        {
            base.InitializeNewDomain(appDomainInfo);
            appDomainInfo.ShadowCopyFiles = "true";
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the `app.config` of your assembly you can tell it to use your loader dll.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
    <runtime>
      <appDomainManagerType value="DomainManager.ShadowDomainManager" />
      <appDomainManagerAssembly
         value="DomainManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Now your exe and any DLL's it loads (that are stored in the application directory or its subdirectories) will be loaded in to a Shadow Copied App Domain and can be deleted/replaced while in use.